# Submitting an up vote to a question submits unposted answer too

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting, posting

I was writing [an answer to a bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68375873/yii2-usuario-custom-fields-in-social-connect-page/68544065#68544065) and was waiting for the OP's reply to my comments under the question. Meanwhile I had the answer written, I upvoted the question and in the result it upvoted the question along with submitting the answer to the question too, which I wasn't expecting to happen.

Does anyone come across the same issue? I deleted the answer to the question, and you can see the deleted post under that question if you have the privilege.

#### OS details

[Ubuntu 20.04.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa)

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
```

#### Browser details

[image]

Comment: Couldn't repro this on Chrome / Win 10

Comment: No repro on FF91 either

Comment: No repro on FF90 / Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

You must’ve posted the answer by mistake, it was posted *5 minutes before you voted on the question*, so it wasn’t the voting that did this.

- your answer was [posted at 11:31 UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68544065/timeline) (timeline link, visible to the author and users with 10k+ only)
- the question was upvoted at 11:36 UTC; the OP only received one vote on the day so the [exact time is easy to spot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13571872/sala?tab=reputation&sort=time).

You only noticed that you had posted the answer by mistake right after you voted and deleted it a few seconds afterwards, still at 11:36.

Comment: that makes sense sorry for bothering guys